# How to get time , date and year in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, date

Hello guys I am developing an asp.net MVC3 project, I would like to ask how to get the `time date and year` from the server side. For example scenario I have 2 PC, PC 1 is my server and PC 2 is for my client side. The PC 1 Time is `8/10/2016`and for my PC 2 is `8/5/2016`. And I have a `Button` for capturing a time for the log.in. What I want now is the time that I want to capture is the time in the PC 1(server side) not the time in my current PC (PC2 / client side). And also I have a text box / label that determine the current date of the Server side`(but failed to do it)`. For these two problems how to solve?. Because I am only using the code `DateTime.Now` for capturing the `time` and getting the `date`.

For the second scenario my current `date and time` in my PC 2(client side) is `8/5/2016` if I change my `date` in PC 2 the `labe` which contain the `date` from the server side(but failed to do) is also changing. What code should I use?.

Comment: Any code run server side would get the servers point of view..

Answer (score 1):

Talking about ASP.NET MVC, `DateTime.Now` will always return **server time** in any part of your controllers or other server-side code, since this code is executed on **server**.
You may only have issues with client-side time when passing it from \ to client-side, f.i. HTML form / JavaScript code.

There are also no such things like "text box" and "label" in ASP.NET MVC.
Perhaps, you are confusing the technologies.

Comment: Sorry if lack of information. For the `label` it only display in my cshtml for displaying the date.

Comment: it will return the server time not on my current PC`(client)`?. that's what you mean right?.

Answer (score 0):

If you what to get Client date.. You must use any javascript like **getDate();**

MVC is Structure gives to you for write code with respect to the requirement,
'Views' side Controls Client part (ie, PC2) and 'Controller' side controls Server side. But it view gives date from server. So run any javascript in scripts side update labels.